# Saving into a Database RichTextBox formatted in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a `RichTextBox` where I insert code into it from Visual Studio. When I paste it inside of `RichTextBox`, the code will be formatted nicely with colors and that kind of stuff from Visual Studio Editor.

This `RichTextBox` input will be inserted into my database in Access in a Memo field.

This is my code from Save Button:

```
private void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con = new OleDbConnection(cs.DBConn);
        con.Open();

        string queryInsert = @"INSERT INTO tblFixing(CodBefore)
                               VALUES
                               (@CodBefore)";
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryInsert);
        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@CodBefore", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "CodBefore"));

        cmd.Parameters["@CodBefore"].Value = rchCodBefore.Text.Trim();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        cmdSave.Enabled = false;

        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error\nDetalhes: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

If I change the parameter of it to `cmd.Parameters["@CodBefore"].Value = rchCodBefore.Rtf` it does not solve my issue.

Basically I want to save it formatted and load it formatted. When I copy some code from Visual Studio in C# and paste it into that `RichTextBox` the lines are formatted and colored but after saving it and reloading into that `RichTextBox` it is black.

I wanna know how to save this field formatted. Could you help me?

Comment: Could you clarify the question you are asking, and exactly what problem you are having? See [ask] and [mcve]. Welcome to SO, by the way.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: So in the field you see rft code (you should do, you will not see it formatted)?  When you load it back into a richtextbox you do so via .Rtf and not .Text ?

Comment: Already edited the post. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: I wanna see it as Rtf and not Text @AlexK.

Comment: What happens when you use `rchCodBefore.Rtf` ? is it saving properly in the db? How are you trying to display the text from database into the RichTextBox ?

Comment: @you showed the save (and commented that saving .rtf didn't "work"), but no load - save .rtf, load .rtf.  Though, I suspect if you saved .rtf, loaded .text, the issue would become readily apparent.